# Reactstrap tooltip causes an error: The target 'TooltipExample' could not be identified in the dom

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have following the code example regarding [tooltips](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/) 
in Reactstrap:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    tooltipOpen: true
  };
}
.
.
.
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Somewhere in here is a <a href="#" id="TooltipExample">tooltip</a>.</p>
      <Tooltip 
        placement="right" 
        isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen} 
        target="TooltipExample" 
        toggle={this.toggle}>
        Hello world!
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Error: The target 'TooltipExample' could not be identified in the dom, tip: check spelling

Everything works ok if the initial state is `tooltipOpen: false`. **But** I would like the tooltip to appear when the user loads the page...

What should I do?

Answer (score 16):

In constructor, tooltipOpen should be `false`.

And then, in componentDidMount, switch tooltipOpen from `false` to `true`

This is code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    tooltipOpen: false,
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    tooltipOpen: true,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Since the introduction of React Hooks this error can be avoided using the following approach.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { UncontrolledTooltip } from 'reactstrap'

const ToolTipExample = () => {

    const ref = useRef(null)

    return (
        <div >
            <p ref={ref}>Hello World</p>
            <UncontrolledTooltip target={ref}>
                Tooltip message goes here :D
            </UncontrolledTooltip>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This will also work with the `Tooltip` component.

Comment: I believe this is needed because the tooltip's sibling is not in the DOM yet while the tooltip is being created, so you need to give it a ref which is valid right away. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across the same problem, the issue was the initial value, the initial value must be `false` if you put `true` as initial value the popover looking for the `target` element that could not be rendered yet, so if you want to open popover as component render update the state in `componentDidMount` hook.

```
/* initial value must be false */
state = { isPopoverOpen: false };

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    isPopoverOpen: true,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if anyone needs to know this. But I got the same error when I added the id property to a component instead of an HTML element. Obviously fixed it by adding a wrapping element to my component and placing my id there.

Comment: Can you provide any example how you did that?