# Reactstrap Tooltip throws target could not be identified in the dom error with dynamic IDs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I had a perfectly working custom Reactstrap Tooltip component that I use in my forms. However, I recently discovered that there was a target ID clash if I use the same `name` property more than once, which causes some Tooltips to not show up.

Therefore, I decided to append a random string to the tooltip in order to get unique IDs like this:

```js
// instead of just `Tooltip-${name}`, I use `Math.random()`:
const tooltipId = `Tooltip-${name}-${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)}`;
```

I then use the `tooltipId` constant I just created as an `id` and `target`.

However, this generates the following error as soon as the user hovers over the `(i)` icon:

```
The target 'Tooltip-tp1-27tha' could not be identified in the dom, tip: check spelling
```

Can anyone explain **why is this only happening when generating a random ID?**

Here is a sandbox to demonstrate the issue: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-shape-thj00?file=/src/CustomTooltip.jsx

Comment: had this issue and solved from the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68636620/4342108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your tooltipId on creation of the component and not in the render method.
Because the state changes, it is re-rendered and therefore has a new tooltipid.

```js
class CustomTooltip extends Component {
  tooltipId = `Tooltip-${this.props.name}-${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)}`

...
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out, but I still don't understand why the state changes? Is it `Math.random()` that triggers a re-render?

Comment: No, the `tooltipOpen` in state changes on hover, so that's why it re-renders

Comment: Right, spot on 